# Java: generic interfaces and functions in such

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am still experimenting with how Java handles generics. I stumbled upon the fact/issue/thing that if you have a generic interface like `A<T>`, you cannot really check afterwards if some object is actually implementing `A<B>` or `A<C>`.

I wondered if that could cause actual problems.

Now I have tried this code:

```
static interface A<T> { void foo(T obj); }
static class B implements A<B> {
    public void foo(B obj) { obj.bar(); }       
    void bar() {}
}
static {
    assert (new B() instanceof A<?>);
    ((A<?>) new B()).foo(new Object());
}
```

This gives me this error (for the `foo`-call):

```
The method foo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Main.A<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

I wonder why that is. Eclipse tells me that the signature of `foo` after the cast to `A<?>` is `foo(? obj)` which I thought is the same as `foo(Object obj)`.

The `assert` succeeds.

What I tried to figure out is at what point exactly does it cast the object when I call the  `foo` function.

Also, how can I call `foo` from `A<?>`? This is the thing I actually need to be able to do. Or is that impossible with any other parameter than `null`?

A more real-world example where I actually wonder about this: I use the `Comparable<T>` interface a lot. That case is actually even more complicated; I might open another question about that if this here doesn't answer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many have clarified that point about `?` but noone has really answered the main question yet, so here it is:

It is possible to call `A#foo` like this:

```
((A) new B()).foo(new Object());
```

The cast then is done **inside** of `foo`.

Comment: This turns A into a `raw type` (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257) which is generally considered fantastically bad programming practice.

Comment: May I know who did the downvote? Of course this is bad practice and the compiler also warns about this but this is still the exact answer to the question. It is exactly the thing which I wanted to know here. I am not actually using this. But a downvote looks like it is a wrong answer, which it is not (at least from what I have understand). If you think this answer is wrong, please explain why and don't just downvote without any comment...

Answer (score 10):

> I wonder why that is. Eclipse tells me that the signature of foo after the cast to A is foo(? obj) which I thought is the same as foo(Object obj).

Nope, absolutely not.  Imagine `A<T>` is `List<T>` with `foo(T)` being `add(T)` and so `A<?>` is `List<?>`.  Should you be able to do this?

```
 List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<?> wcList = strList;
 wcList.add(Integer.valueOf(6));  //possible if add(?) is same as add(Object)

 //...
 String str = strList.get(0);
```

Of course not, since you'd get a ClassCastException in the final line.

What `foo(?)` really means is that the method applies to some *unknown but specific* type.  You can't typically invoke these methods unless you pass null as the parameter, which is acceptable to assign to *any* reference type.

Comment: Just to clarify (because this is the most important thing for me): There is no way to call `foo` from `A<?>`?

Comment: @Albert: not without passing null as the parameter value, no.  You could always invoke it by using the raw type `((A)someA).foo(param)` but obviously that would be completely discarding any type safety you wanted to have.

Comment: Ah, so instead of using `A<?>`, I can use just `A`? That was the actual thing I wanted to know here, thanks! :) But my other questions still stay open then (e.g. where is the cast done).

Answer (score 3):

If you have "`foo(? obj)`" then the `?` could be any type. If it is say `String` then you can't pass, say, an `Integer` to it. All you can pass is `null`.

Casting and use of `instanceof` should normally be avoided unless unavoidable (such as implementing `equals`), particularly with generics.

Comment: Just to clarify: So there is no way at all that I can call `foo` from `A<?>` with any other parameter than `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct because it does a *compile-cast* test on compile-time.

```
((A<?>) new B()).foo(new Object());
```

is errornous because the compiler expected

```
((A<?>) new B()).foo(A object)....
```

meaning that it wanted anything of type A or its children. `Object` is the parent of `A` and it doesn't match the compile-test Parameter type for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

When you check if an instance of `B` is an instance of `A<?>` you just do the same thing as `new B() instanceof A`. You don't really check how `T` is set, it's just "something".

Later in the code with the cast, you tell that you'll use `B` as a `A<?>` so the variable will have the characteristic of a `A` but the generic type is still "something". This "something" exists and is probably a specified class but your don't care of the exact type.

That's why when you use the `foo()` method which take a `T` in parameter, you can't pass a "something" in parameter, because you don't know what it is, it could be an `Object` but it could be anything else.

Because of this the compiler tells you `foo(capture#1-of ?)` isn't applicable for the argument `Object`. The needed parameter is "something" but not necessarily an `Object`.

---

#### Then, when would you need this feature ?

For example if you work with a map, if you don't really care of the type of the key (if you only work with the `values()` method for example), you could do something like this :

```
Map<?, V> m
```

This way you won't be able to use features related to the key of the map (but you don't care about that), but you'll be able to use a map with **any** kind of key.

Answer (score 0):

No, `foo(? obj)` is not actually the same as `foo(Object obj)`. The difference is, when the parameter type is `Object`, it's explicitly stating that any type of object is legal. With a parameter type of `?`, the method states that it *does not know* what type of object is legal... therefore nothing is legal except for `null`.

The reasoning for this becomes apparent when you consider a `List` rather than an arbitrary interface. Look at this method:

```
public void foo(List<?> list) {
  list.add(...); // what can we add here?
}
```

The `?` indicates that any type of `List` is acceptable... the `List` passed in could be a `List<String>`, a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Map<Foo, Bar>>`. There's no way of knowing. Note that this is only a problem with methods that *consume* generic parameters, such as `add` or your `foo` method. For methods that *produce* (return) an object of the generic type, it's fine to use such a method and assign the result as an `Object`. This, unlike the consumer method, cannot corrupt the internal state of the generic object.

Also notice that when you call `((A<?>) new B()).foo(new Object())`, you're trying to do something illegal... if something (such as the `Object`) that is not a `B` were to be passed to `B`'s `foo` method, it would explode at runtime. The compiler is correctly preventing you from doing this.

You may also want to check out my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248390/java-generics-collections-max-signature-and-comparator/2248503#2248503) which explains some things about bounded wildcard types and such.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple explanation:

`A<?>` means A of unknown parametrized type. Given

```
A<?> ref = new B()
```

`ref` could point to any A: `A<Object`, `A<String>`, anything. So you can not call `A.foo(new Object())` because in case of `A<?>` reference there is no way to know which parameter `ref.foo()` accepts. Actually the only thing valid is `ref.foo(null)`.