# Where can we use ArrayList< ? extends My_Class>

Tags: java, generics

Where can we `ArrayList<? extends My_Class>` because it won't allow you to add any new element if you declare it of this way:

```
ArrayList<? extends My_Class> obj=new ArrayList<? extends My_Class>();
list.add(new Derived_My_Class()); //this is compilation error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can elements be added to a wildcard generic collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection)

Answer (score 5):

The widely-used acronym for describing these keywords is: PECS: Producer extends - consumer super.

So, if you use "extends" your collection *produces* elements of the given type. So you can't add to it, you can only take from it.

An example usage would be to provide a client of your API with a list:

```
public List<? extends CharSequence> getFoo() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("foo");
    return list;
}
```

Related: [Java generics: Collections.max() signature and Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248390/java-generics-collections-max-signature-and-comparator/2248503#2248503)

Comment: What is the advantage we are trying to get out of it i don't understand because the caller of this method also should define a variable of type List<? extends CharSequence> not even List<String> and later also u can't modify the received variable that's why i don't understand why do we need it

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, your `ArrayList` cannot be used the way it is derived: there is nothing that you can put into it.

What you want for storing `My_Class` and its subclasses is simply `ArrayList<My_Class>`; it will take objects of `My_Class` and all its `DerivedClass` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well...There is no point one will declare ArrayList like this, rather your intentions will be fullfilled by writing

ArrayList< Supertype> obj=new ArrayList< Supertype>();

As per my epxerience, I have seen this notion in method arguments, where you expect your caller to provide a collection of subtypes of particular Supertype (or return from  a method likewise as someone said above). like as follows

```
public getAnimals(List< ? extends Animal> obj){

obj.add(something);    //not allowed

}
```

there are fair chances that you can add donkeys, monkeys and birds etc in your List of certain type say (Monkey). and get  classCastException while getting from it.

That's why It not allowed in this case. read Effective Java by Josh Bloch. he has explained it well with producer consumer analogy(PECS)

Comment: Ahm... What? Yes, that's exactly what I would want in certain cases. Does not adress the question

Comment: supposing that donkeys, monkeys and birds all of them derive from `Animal` then... what's the problem for storing them in a `ArrayList<Animal>`?? and... where is the potential disaster??

Comment: I don't expect myself to be such a dumb. i am sorry..refer updated answer